# Will facebook, google logins and signup included in Firebase free plan?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using google, facebook and firebase email authentication in my app and its possible that we get a big users in our app

so will google, facebook user count in Firebase authentication free and paid prices or not

and also is there any limit for facebook authentication??

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication is always free.  There are no costs per user, and you can easily sign up millions of users.

Comment: but according to firebase pricing plan. we can only add 10000 user for free later we have to pay a big amount

Comment: That's only for phone authentication.  Everything else is free.  Read that page of documentation again very carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The cost is based on the number of MAU (Monthly Active users).
The first 50000 are for free, after that, you will be charged 0.0055$ per 1 MAU.

example:

1. 19000 MAU = 0$
2. 50000 MAU = 0$
3. 51000 MAU = 5.5$
4. ... and so on

references:

1. https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing check the last
   table
2. pricing calaculator: https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator#tab=identity-platform

Hope my answer was of Help